# f2py error: undefined symbol

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I need to wrap a simply fortran90 code with f2py. The fortran module "test.f90" is

```
module util

contains

FUNCTION gasdev(idum)
implicit none
INTEGER(kind=4), intent(inout) :: idum
REAL(kind=8) :: gasdev, ran2
print*,idum
gasdev = ran2(idum)
return
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION ran2(idum)
implicit none
INTEGER(kind=4), intent(inout) :: idum
REAL(kind=8) :: ran2
print*,idum
ran2=2.D0
return
END FUNCTION
end module util
```

and then I wrap it with

```
f2py  -m test -c test.f90
```

but when I import it in python

```
In [2]: import test
```

it prompted me with error saying

```
ImportError: ./test.so: undefined symbol: ran2_
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In function gasdev you declare ran2 as an external function. As you then don't link in any such function importing the module will fail.

Instead, remove the declaration of ran2 in gasdev, in which case the ran2 call uses the explicit interface to the ran2 function in the module, and everything works.

Comment: thanks. the depressing part is that the code works well in fortran compiler itself, and the error spit out by f2py is not quite illuminating to me...

Comment: Sure, compiling will work fine. Linking might be another matter though, unless you have an external procedure ran2 somewhere in your codebase.

Comment: I used to think that I have to designate an external function using `external` keyword, never realized that it is already so when I declare it...